Changing cloth modifer during the simulation creates a frozen result
I noticed that when the modifier of the cloth is intentionally changed after a certain number of frames, the result is not an animation but a static image of the final result. If I keep the modifier unchanged, the result is what we expect without any issues.
The scenario in this piece of code is:
A cloth is being dropped onto a cube. After 200 frames, I changed the cloth modifier to make it a solid piece (rigid body) and then continued the simulation for 50 more frames.
import bpy

def setup_scene():
    # Clear existing objects
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
    bpy.ops.object.delete()

    # Set scene settings
    bpy.context.scene.frame_start = 1
    bpy.context.scene.frame_end = 250

    # Create a cube as a platform
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=2, location=(0, 0, -1))
    cube = bpy.context.object
    cube.name = "Cube"
    
    # Add rigid body to the cube (passive)
    bpy.ops.rigidbody.object_add()
    cube.rigid_body.type = 'PASSIVE'
    cube.rigid_body.collision_shape = 'BOX'
    
    # Add collision modifier for cloth interaction
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='COLLISION')

def add_cloth(location, size=5):
    # Create a cloth (plane)
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(size=size, location=location)
    cloth = bpy.context.object
    cloth.name = "Cloth"
    
    # Subdivide the cloth mesh for better simulation
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.subdivide(number_cuts=20)
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
    
    # Add cloth physics
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='CLOTH')
    cloth_mod = cloth.modifiers['Cloth']
    cloth_mod.settings.quality = 5
    cloth_mod.settings.mass = 0.3

    # Bake the cloth simulation for 200 frames
    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(1)
    bpy.ops.ptcache.bake_all(bake=True)

def convert_cloth_to_rigid_body(cloth):
    # Apply the cloth modifier to freeze its shape at frame 201
    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(201)
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier='Cloth')
    
    # Add rigid body to the cloth (active)
    bpy.ops.rigidbody.object_add()
    cloth.rigid_body.type = 'ACTIVE'
    cloth.rigid_body.collision_shape = 'MESH'
    cloth.rigid_body.mass = 5

    # Clear and rebake the simulation for rigid body dynamics
    bpy.context.scene.rigidbody_world.point_cache.frame_start = 201
    bpy.context.scene.rigidbody_world.point_cache.frame_end = 250
    bpy.ops.ptcache.free_bake_all()
    bpy.ops.ptcache.bake_all(bake=True)

# Setup scene and perform simulation
setup_scene()
add_cloth((0, 0, 5))
cloth = bpy.data.objects['Cloth']
convert_cloth_to_rigid_body(cloth) # THIS CREATES OUR PROBLEM


# Save the blend file
import os

path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
simulation_file = os.path.join(path, 'simulation.blend')
if os.path.exists(simulation_file):
    os.remove(simulation_file)
bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile(filepath=os.path.join(path, "simulation.blend"))
```

